# ArgumentError, wrong number of arguments (2 for 0) in create action, works on Heroku but not on local server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, save, argument-error

I recently had a RoR application developed for me by a third party and now I'm on my own to add future features that I want. It works on Heroku, but when I try to run it on localhost:3000, I get an ArgumentError. I have not changed any of the code, I just pulled it from github and tried to run it on a local development server to implement new changes. I've asked them about this problem, but they are not sure of the cause, so here goes...

We're running ruby 1.9.2, rails 3.0.7

Whenever I try to save a project on my site, or whenever .save is called on an object, I get an ArgumentError, wrong number of arguments (2 for 0).

Application Trace

```
app/controllers/users/projects_controller.rb:24:in `create'
```

Full Trace

```
activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/ordered_hash.rb:16:in `block in to_yaml'
/home/squizzleflip/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/deprecated.rb:19:in `call'
/home/squizzleflip/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/deprecated.rb:19:in `block in quick_emit'
/home/squizzleflip/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:296:in `dump_coder'
/home/squizzleflip/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:61:in `accept'
/home/squizzleflip/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:36:in `<<'
/home/squizzleflip/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:165:in `dump'
activerecord (3.0.7) lib/active_record/base.rb:1720:in `block in arel_attributes_values'
activerecord (3.0.7) lib/active_record/base.rb:1713:in `each'
activerecord (3.0.7) lib/active_record/base.rb:1713:in `arel_attributes_values'
activerecord (3.0.7) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:265:in `create'
activerecord (3.0.7) lib/active_record/timestamp.rb:47:in `create'
activerecord (3.0.7) lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:277:in `block in create'
activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:414:in `_run_create_callbacks'
activerecord (3.0.7) lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:277:in `create'
activerecord (3.0.7) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:246:in `create_or_update'
activerecord (3.0.7) lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:273:in `block in create_or_update'
activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:424:in `_run_save_callbacks'
activerecord (3.0.7) lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:273:in `create_or_update'
activerecord (3.0.7) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:39:in `save'
activerecord (3.0.7) lib/active_record/validations.rb:43:in `save'
activerecord (3.0.7) lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:21:in `save'
activerecord (3.0.7) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:240:in `block (2 levels) in save'
activerecord (3.0.7) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:292:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
activerecord (3.0.7)     lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:139:in `transaction'
activerecord (3.0.7) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:207:in `transaction'
activerecord (3.0.7) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:290:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
activerecord (3.0.7) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:240:in `block in save'
activerecord (3.0.7) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:251:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
activerecord (3.0.7) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:239:in `save'
app/controllers/users/projects_controller.rb:24:in `create'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in `send_action'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:150:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:11:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:448:in `_run__334044120__process_action__677517956__callbacks'
activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:410:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:94:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:119:in `process'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:41:in `process'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:138:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:178:in `block in action'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:62:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:62:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:27:in `call'
rack-mount (0.6.14) lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:148:in `block in call'
rack-mount (0.6.14) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:93:in `block in recognize'
rack-mount (0.6.14) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:68:in `optimized_each'
rack-mount (0.6.14) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:92:in `recognize'
rack-mount (0.6.14) lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:139:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:493:in `call'
warden (1.0.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.0.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.0.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in   `call'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.2.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:182:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:149:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:302:in `call'
activerecord (3.0.7) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:32:in `block in call'
activerecord (3.0.7) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:28:in `cache'
activerecord (3.0.7) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:12:in `cache'
activerecord (3.0.7) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:31:in `call'
activerecord (3.0.7)    lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:354:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:46:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:416:in `_run_call_callbacks'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:44:in `call'
rack (1.2.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:106:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:48:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:47:in `call'
railties (3.0.7) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:13:in `call'
rack (1.2.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.2.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `block in call'
<internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize'
rack (1.2.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:30:in `call'
railties (3.0.7) lib/rails/application.rb:168:in `call'
railties (3.0.7) lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
railties (3.0.7) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.2.4) lib/rack/content_length.rb:13:in `call'
rack (1.2.4) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:52:in `service'
/home/squizzleflip/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-  p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:111:in `service'
/home/squizzleflip/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-  p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:70:in `run'
/home/squizzleflip/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:183:in  `block in start_thread'
```

the code from projects_controller, line 24 is the if statement

```
def create
    @project = Project.new(params[:project])
    @project.memberships.build(:user_id => current_profile.id, :pending => false)

    if @project.save
      redirect_to destination, :notice => 'Project was successfully created.'
    else
      build_project_associations_for_nested_forms
      render :action => 'new'
    end
   end
```

I'm a bit new at this, so I'm not quite sure what else is needed to determine the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried running something other than WEBrick (assuming you're using that)? Try installing Thin (gem install thin) and see if the problem persists.

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly! I can't believe it was something so small, you're a genius!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have got all the required gem, run bundle install:

```
bundle install
```

Restart the app, hopefully that helps.

Comment: I've run bundle install and got all the required gems but no change in the error. The applications runs until I try to save.